# Spark 2.1.0, ML RandomForest: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.maxBy

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

I am trying to fit an ML Cross Validator on a DataFrame of the following Schema:

```
root
 |-- userID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)
 |-- label: double (nullable = true)
```

I am getting a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.maxBy` when I fit the CrossValidator.

I have read [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/16377) bug report, it says that this exception happens there is no feautres:

> **In the case of empty features** we fail with a better error message stating:
>   DecisionTree requires number of features > 0, but was given an empty features vector
>   **Instead of the cryptic error message:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.max**

In my case, I do have thousands of features, so I am sure that the features DataFrame is not empty.

**What could be another reason for this exception?**

I am running the cluster on EMR, and here is the code if that helps (the DataFrame name is `featuresDF`, and before I fit the `CrossValidator` I verified that there is no empty features):

```
val rf = new RandomForestClassifier()
                        .setLabelCol("label")
                        .setFeaturesCol("features")

val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(rf))

val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder()
                    .addGrid(rf.numTrees, Array(500, 1000))
                    .addGrid(rf.maxDepth, Array(15, 25))
                    .build()

val evaluator = new BinaryClassificationEvaluator()
                    .setLabelCol("label")
                    .setMetricName("areaUnderPR")

val cv = new CrossValidator()
                    .setEstimator(pipeline)
                    .setEvaluator(evaluator)
                    .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
                    .setNumFolds(3)

val model = cv.fit(featuresDF)
```

Comment: can you share the code producing this error?

Comment: @mtoto I have added the code. thanks

Comment: I had the same error with Random Forests in Spark when a given column had a constant value. I think it has to do with this solved issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18036. It looks like Random Forests don't handle edge cases very well.

Comment: OK then, we will hope that this issue will get solved in 2.2.0 then, I couldn't find any solution other than rolling back to 2.0.1